# MPI Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

When writing code in C/C++ using MPI, if memory is allocated before MPI_Init is called, how do each of the processes view that memory?  From a test program, I can see that sometimes it's OK and others it isn't.  Does the standard define this?  I can't tell if the memory allocation is copied over to the other processes during MPI_Init, of if I just got lucky because all the processes are 'currently' on a single (multi-core) CPU.

Comment: There should be no copying at MPI_Init. Before calling MPI_Init, each process allocates the same memory, so everybody should be able to see it, right?

Comment: I guess that is what I don't understand -- befor MPI_Init, do the other processes even exist?  If not, then allocating memory before MPI_Init would only allocate memory to the 'master' (id=0) process?

Comment: Yes. You can test this by writing a hello world program without calling MPI_Init, and execute it in parallel - you will spawn n independent processes, and each will say "hello". Calling MPI_Init establishes the environment (MPI_Comm) which creates links between processes and allows them to say who they are (e.g. what is my id?).

Comment: Note that in some MPI implementations, only one process exists before MPI_Init.  During MPI_Init is when those implementations will actually spawn the other processes in the MPI job.  So truly portable MPI programs won't do anything before MPI_Init or at least will make very minimal assumptions about what happens before/during/after MPI_Init.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of -- is there some definitive reference that establishes if/how this is defined?  Do you know if the MPI Standard mentions this?  I've tested MPICH2 and msmpi on a Windows Server 2008 R2 HPC Edition and the processes do spawn when the exe is loaded.  I'm guessing that if other MPI implementations don't perform this way, then this behavior is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Each process is spawned at executable load-time. If any memory is allocated before a call to MPI_Init, each process knows that data. However, before MPI_Init is called, processes are not aware of themselves or each other. Calling MPI_Init and MPI_Comm_world initializes MPI environment and returns you MPI_Comm, which allows you to establish connection between processes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks IRO-bot!  I wrote the HelloWorld.cpp and tested it; here is a copy for anyone else that is interested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numprocs;
    int myid = 0;
    std::cout << "Hello MPI World, from process " << myid << "!! " << std::endl;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

    if(myid == 0)
        std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hello MPI World, from process " << myid << "!! " << std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output from:  mpiexec -n 4 HelloMPIWorld

Hello MPI World, from process 0!!
Hello MPI World, from process 0!!
Hello MPI World, from process 0!!
Hello MPI World, from process 0!!

Hello MPI World, from process 0!!
Hello MPI World, from process 3!!
Hello MPI World, from process 1!!
Hello MPI World, from process 2!!